# Relationship of \\, \newline, \raggedright, \RaggedRight, and parindent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, ragged2e

I'm trying to understand if there is anyway to get `\\`, when in `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight`, to produce a new line that is *not* indented, while `\parindent` or `\RaggedRightParindent` are set in order to have indented paragraphs. This is necessary for certain types of text blocks (e.g., an address or a block of text with "header" info [e.g., for homework]), in which I want to set each line on its own with a hard break and no indentation. I know that people on this board strongly discourage using `\\`, but this seems like an appropriate use. Furthermore, as I'm exporting to Tex from markdown, via Pandoc, `\\` are used for markdown line breaks (indicated by two or more spaces at the end of a line). I actually get the desired output when text is set according to memoir's default, that is, with neither `\RaggedRight` nor `\raggedright`.

So, is there any easy way to do this? I can't find anything about the relationship between `\RaggedRight` or `\raggedright` and `\\` or `\newline` in either the ragged2e or memoir docs. My hope is to do this without other markup in the text, just adjustments in my preamble, as I write in more-or-less pure markdown and then automatically convert it to Latex. Of course, this might not be possible, but it seems so from the third example.

Here are my MWEs:

In `\RaggedRight`, which is my preferred way of setting text, both `\\` and `\newline` indent the new lines (see both the header block on top and the address in the middle).

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
\RaggedRight
%\raggedright
%\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\noindent
LastName\newline Line 2\\Line 3\\Line 4\\29 August 2014

\section{Lorem Ipsum}\label{lip}

\lipsum[1-2]

And here is my address, that I want to have set flush left with no indentation:\\
My Name\newline 7999 Any St Apt 3\\Los Angeles CA  99999\\
With more text, that also should be flowed in the paragraph, with no indentation, coming after the address. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: \RaggedRight indentation]

In `\raggedright`, `\\`, but not `\newline`, indents the new lines (see both the header block on top and the address in the middle).

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
%\RaggedRight
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\noindent
LastName\newline Line 2\\Line 3\\Line 4\\29 August 2014

\section{Lorem Ipsum}\label{lip}

\lipsum[1-2]

And here is my address, that I want to have set flush left with no indentation:\\
My Name\newline 7999 Any St Apt 3\\Los Angeles CA  99999\\
With more text, that also should be flowed in the paragraph, with no indentation, coming after the address. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: \raggedright indentation]

Finally, with neither `\RaggedRight` nor `\raggedright` in place, I actually get my desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
%\RaggedRight
%\raggedright
%\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\noindent
LastName\newline Line 2\\Line 3\\Line 4\\29 August 2014

\section{Lorem Ipsum}\label{lip}

\lipsum[1-2]

And here is my address, that I want to have set flush left with no indentation:\\
My Name\newline 7999 Any St Apt 3\\Los Angeles CA  99999\\
With more text, that also should be flowed in the paragraph, with no indentation, coming after the address. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: indentation with no ragged text]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) updates both `\newline` and `\\` to function differently. Before updating, it stores the original set of macros. The original functionality can be reinstated by placing

```
\makeatletter
\let\@gnewline\@raggedtwoe@saved@gnewline% Restore original functionality of \newline
\let\\\@raggedtwoe@savedcr% Restore original functionality of \\
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble.

---

Another idea is to set the contents you want flushed left as part of an unbreakable structure like a `tabular`. I would guess this seems sufficient as a break across the page within the address might be confusion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
\RaggedRight
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  LastName \\Line 2\\ Line 3\\Line 4\\29 August 2014
\end{tabular}

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum[1-2]

And here is my address, that I want to have set flush left with no indentation: \strut

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  My Name\\ 7999 Any St Apt 3\\Los Angeles CA  99999
\end{tabular}

\noindent
With more text, that also should be flowed in the paragraph, with no indentation, coming after the address. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks—this would certainly work, but, as I just clarified in the question, I'm really hoping just to adjust the settings for either `\RaggedRight` or `\raggedright` in my preamble and not have to alter anything in the text itself, which is converted from pure markdown. But thanks for the idea!

Comment: @hgv: In both instance (`\newline` and ``\\``), LaTeX issues a `\par`, which inserts the regular paragraph indent. Without [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) there is no adjustment to the newline-style macros and they work as expected. You can restore the way `\newline` functioned by adding `\makeatletter \let\@gnewline\@raggedtwoe@saved@gnewline \makeatother` to your preamble, for example. Similarly, `\makeatletter \let\\\@raggedtwoe@savedcr \makeatother` will restore the way ``\\`` functioned before loading `ragged2e`.

Comment: Thanks, @Werner! Exactly what I was looking for—I should get more familiar with the actual code of ragged2e.